# Replace specific part of a string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, string, replace

I've got a table with multiple columns, `APGRPID`, `VIRTKEY`, `LFDNR` and `PARAMETERLIST`. I want to change a part of some strings in the `PARAMETERLIST` column.
In the `PARAMETERLIST` I want to replace the "value" for the `PATH=` setting.

Table:

| APGRPID | VIRTKEY | LFDNR | PARAMETERLIST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1091.000000 | 121.000000 | 1 | KF=138;SCANANDSEND=TRUE;ENDBARCODE=999999999999;PATH=K:\SSTEST;BARCODELENGTH=8 |
| 2092.000000 | 130.000000 | 8 | KF=138; PATH=s:\ |
| 2101.000000 | 114.000000 | 3 | DESIGNATION=JOB; KF=81; PATH=w:; SENDALLDATA=TRUE |
| 2102.000000 | 116.000000 | 3 | KF=76; PATH=\srv05\L3OERAPMFC; SENDALLDATA=TRUE |
| 2303.000000 | 114.000000 | 2 | KF=386; PATH=W:; SENDALLDATA=TRUE |

The main problem I have is the randomness of the position of the `PATH=` parameter in the `PARAMETERLIST` column and the variability of the number of elements in the column if I try to `CROSS APPLY` a `STRING_SPLIT()` or anything.

Platform: Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise (Ver. 14.0.1000.169)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your question is difficult to answer because it's unclear what platform you are using.

Comment: As an aside, though, if you are using a relational database product, please consider either parsing the `PARAMETERLIST` value and storing each parameter in a separate column (so that you can manipulate their values much more easily), or do this kind of processing in the application. Many SQL products have a set of string functions, and that can be very handy, but what you are trying to do here (change the value of a field/column) is something that an RDBMS is designed to do natively *if* you store your data in a normalised fashion. Just saying.

Comment: Hello Andriy, thank you for your answer. We're using Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise (Ver. 14.0.1000.169). I've edited the initiating post.

Comment: Andriy, please provide me a code example :-)

Comment: Build 14.0.1000.169 is SQL Server 2017 not SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your test data, this will parse out the section of the string you want between either the first semi-colon after the `PATH=`, or the end of the string if that doesn't exist. From here, you should be able to use an *update* to replace that section of the string.

Further reading: [Get The Text Between Two Delimiters](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/t-sql-get-the-text-between-two-delimiters/)

```
SELECT 
    x.*,
    SUBSTRING(x.PARAMETERLIST,
        CHARINDEX('PATH=', x.PARAMETERLIST) + LEN('PATH='),
        CASE WHEN x.PARAMETERLIST NOT LIKE '%PATH=%;%'
             THEN LEN(x.PARAMETERLIST)
             ELSE CHARINDEX(';', x.PARAMETERLIST, CHARINDEX('PATH=', x.PARAMETERLIST) + LEN('PATH='))
                  - LEN('PATH=') - CHARINDEX('PATH=', x.PARAMETERLIST)
        END
             ) AS parsed_string
FROM
(
    VALUES
        ('KF=138;SCANANDSEND=TRUE;ENDBARCODE=999999999999;PATH=K:\SSTEST;BARCODELENGTH=8'),
        ('KF=138; PATH=s:\'),
        ('DESIGNATION=JOB; KF=81; PATH=w:; SENDALLDATA=TRUE'),
        ('KF=76; PATH=\srv05\L3OERAPMFC; SENDALLDATA=TRUE'),
        ('KF=386; PATH=W:; SENDALLDATA=TRUE')
) AS x(PARAMETERLIST);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to change a part of some strings in the PARAMETERLIST column.

This is just one of the reasons that you do not store *multiple* data items in a *single* column.

Any "string" manipulation on these values is going to be complicated, cumbersome and, most importantly, **slow**.  Don't do it (any more).

*Normalise* your data and break these mini-monoliths out into something more sensible, perhaps like this:

```
+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+
| APGRPID     | VIRTKEY    | LFDNR | PARAM_NAME    | PARAM_VALUE  |
+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+ 
| 1091.000000 | 121.000000 |     1 | KF            | 138          | 
| 1091.000000 | 121.000000 |     1 | SCANANDSEND   | TRUE         | 
| 1091.000000 | 121.000000 |     1 | ENDBARCODE    | 999999999999 | 
| 1091.000000 | 121.000000 |     1 | PATH          | K:\SSTEST    | 
| 1091.000000 | 121.000000 |     1 | BARCODELENGTH | 8            | 
| 2092.000000 | 130.000000 |     8 | KF            | 138          | 
| 2092.000000 | 130.000000 |     8 | PATH          | s:\          | 
+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+
```

Sure, it *doesn't* look as "natural" to you and me but, as far as your *database* is concerned, this *is* the way to go.

Alternatively, you *might* consider a column for each parameter - it depends on how often the "list" of possible parameters changes and, whilst it means you can have the correct Data Type for each parameter, it *may* actually wind up being more fiddly to work with, having to second-guess whether each retrieved value is NULL or not.
YMMV.

```
+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+-----+-----------+-------------+
| APGRPID     | VIRTKEY    | LFDNR | BARCODELENGTH | ENDBARCODE   | KF  | PATH      | SCANANDSEND | 
+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+-----+-----------+-------------+
| 1091.000000 | 121.000000 |     1 |           138 | 999999999999 | 138 | K:\SSTEST | TRUE        | 
| 2091.000000 | 130.000000 |     8 | NULL          | NULL         | 138 | S:\       | NULL        | 
+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+--------------+-----+-----------+-------------+
```